# Deep Learning Architecture for regression problem

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks

I have a regression problem where I want to estimate 10 real value outputs (c1,..., c10) from 5 real value inputs (p0,..., p4).

[image]

I tested many deep networks architectures such as: 5 -> 512 ->512 -> 512 -> 128 -> 128 -> 128 -> 10, which RELU activation function and Adamax optimizer with a learning rate of 0.005.

However, for all the tested architectures, learning rates, activation functions... My Loss function converge to a value that I found not optimal.

[image]

How can I improve the results of my regression ?

Do you have any suggestions of other models or architectures to use ?

On which hyperparameter I can play to not converge quickly ?

Comment: Without more knowledge about the data, there's no recipe for this other than trial-and-error. But, you should at least first try a simpler approach by using 10 random forests to predict each of your outputs individually.

Comment: Have you tried a simpler MLP or a SVM? As Alex says, what kind of data is that?